# xmgrace: legend customization from batch script in bash environment

Tags: bash, xmgrace

Using the gracebat utility of xm-grace package I am using the following command in my bash script to plot multiple line graphs and load the legend corresponded to the names of the initial graphs

```
(cd "${output}/!plots" && exec gracebat RMSD.prot* -legend load -batch "${output}/!temp/combo.bfile" -printfile RMSD.prot.png -hardcopy)
```

Here is my batch file

```
HARDCOPY DEVICE \"PNG\"
PAGE SIZE 2560, 2048
xaxis tick major grid on
yaxis tick major grid on
xaxis tick major color \"grey\"
yaxis tick major color \"grey\"
xaxis tick major linewidth 2
yaxis tick major linewidth 2
xaxis tick major linestyle 2
yaxis tick major linestyle 2
xaxis label char size 2.2
yaxis label char size 2.2
xaxis ticklabel char size 2.0
yaxis ticklabel char size 2.0
```

which gives me:
[image]

Which option could I specify to my batch script to modify the apparence of the legend box e.g. to change its position and / or the fond size/ type ?

Could I use some trick (e.g. in bash) to eliminate the repetitive part of the filenames from the legend e.g. "RMSD.prot_6nax" in my case ? For example to rename all of the processed XVG filles on-the-fly by means of removing a part of its filename which should not be appeared on the legend ?

Comment: exactly it's about running the gracebat utility (with batsh script !) in bash environment

Comment: If you knew how you wanted to modify the batch file to achieve your desired result and could include an example of something so modified in the question, that would allow folks who have bash expertise but not xmgrace expertise to answer the question. Otherwise, this requires folks to have knowledge across two quite-different fields.

Comment: That said, worst-case you could create a temporary directory and populate it with symlinks -- each named with the name you want the legend to be, pointing to the full original file.

Comment: does it means to rename initial png filles (to remove the part of the filename which should not be appeared on the legend ) ? Could I rather achive it simply in bash for all of the processed png filles on-the-fly ?

Comment: What you can do with bash is limited by what you can do with xmgrace. _The only obvious way to provide legends to xmgrace is by changing the filenames_, but obviously if it provides a different mechanism then using that is sensible. The thing is, we're mostly bash experts here, _not_ xmgrace experts. If you tell me how to use xmgrace in such a way to make it do what you want, I'll tell you how to make bash use it that way. If you can't, then I can only use functionality that's already in evidence.

Comment: Right, this is actually the question :-) since I am not sure if it would be possible to achive it in xm-grace and believe that the rename initial XVG files in bash could be more valuable strategy ..

Comment: What are the extensions of your input files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming, here, that the names you want are like `6nax_DOPC`, `6nax_DOPE`, etc.

In that case, a crude approach might be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

prefix="RMSD.prot_"
ext=".xvg"
old_wd=$PWD

# create a temporary directory into which we're going to link our output files
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d "${output}/!plots.XXXXXX") || exit
cd "$tmpdir" || exit
for f in ../"${prefix}"*"${ext}"; do
  local_f=${f#../}
  ln -- "$f" . || continue
  mv -- "$local_f" "${local_f#$prefix}" || continue
done
gracebat *"$ext" -legend load -batch "${output}/!temp/combo.bfile" -printfile "$output/!plots/RMSD.prot.png" -hardcopy
gracebat_rc=$?

rm -rf -- "$tmpdir"
exit "$gracebat_rc"
```

We're leaving the original `!plots` directory alone (except for writing output files there), creating a new temporary directory, linking the `.xvg` files there, renaming them to remove the unwanted prefix, and then running gracebat against those new names.

Comment: okay, I gotcha, great solution in bash :-)